# how to install fonts using inno setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal

I want to pre install the fonts for inno setup. I have made a custom inno setup installer with font Aller Light.Now when i run my inno setup for the first time on a client machine. 
The design is not coming proper due to fonts.. but when installer is run once again then design comes proper.

Just to make it more clear,this font is used in the design of my installer,and not in the application which is deployed using this installer.
I just need a way to install the fonts on the client machine before installer executable opens the welcome page,so that design i made for custom setup is proper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bad idea; it's bad practice to modify the user's system prior to the start of the "real" installation phase.  You should strongly consider a redesign to use a system standard font or to use bitmap images of your text in the desired style rather than trying to install a font.

Inno has a mechanism to install a font as part of the installation itself, which will be sufficient for your application (see [FontInstall](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm#FontInstall)).

If you *really* want to go down the bad-practice path, you can probably get something to work with some `InitializeSetup` code that calls `ExtractTemporaryFile` and the [AddFontResource WinAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326.aspx).  (Don't forget to send the broadcast message too.)

Comment: Thanks Miral,I tried using above method but without any help..How to call AddFontResource method in the script.. I used below function..                ExtractTemporaryFile('aller_lt.TTF');
      AddFontResource('aller_lt.TTF'); and Addfontresource is defined as :                                                                    function AddFontResource(FileName: PAnsiChar): Integer; external 'AddFontResourceA@gdi32.dll stdcall';
      SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST,$1D,0,0);

Comment: When you call `ExtractTemporaryFile`, it will be extracted to `{tmp}`. You must copy it from there (with `FileCopy`) to the `{fonts}` folder and register it from there using the full pathname (don't forget to call `ExpandConstant`) if you want it to be permanent.  This is the same process that Inno's standard `FontInstall` method will use. Or you can use [AddFontResourceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183327.aspx) instead with the `FR_PRIVATE` flag to register it as a temporary font.  Then you don't need to copy it or broadcast (but you still need `{tmp}`).